# C++ : calling BIOS interrupt 0x21

Tags: c++, gcc, dos, interrupt, turbo-c++

I remember using a function called

```
geninterrupt(int interrupt_no)
```

(included in `dos.h`) to display a string on the screen in turbo c++ . Now when I try to compile the same program with g++ the compiler yells at me.

```
C:\Users\Krish\Documents\rough.cpp|7|error: '_AH' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Krish\Documents\rough.cpp|8|error: '_DX' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Krish\Documents\rough.cpp|9|error: 'geninterrupt' was not declared in this scope|
```

It seems it doesn't even identify the registers.  What am I doing wrong.  Are these function not a part of c++ standard library? (should I explicitly link the libraries?). If yes how?

Comment: No, this is completely platform-specific. You can use inline assembler to invoke x86-style interrupt. Anyway, this is not the way to display string in modern operating system, it will work only in real mode.

Comment: If the function was in `dos.h`, that's a hint for you to know that it's DOS-specific and not standard.

Comment: Since this question is *highly* platform-specific, it should be tagged more specifically.

Comment: Before we can even begin to help you, what are you trying to achieve? If displaying a string inside a console of some common operating system, `int 10h` is definitely **not** the way to go.

Comment: Does that mean inline assembly in AT&T syntax is my only resort.

Comment: Is it the same for interrupts used to control mouse.like could i use int86() in gcc.

Comment: @Erbureth how would i do it then.

Comment: Do what exactly? Print a string to console under Windows/Linux/Mac? [`std::cout << string;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream)

Comment: @krish You respond to *"what are you trying to achieve?"* with *"how would i do it then"*? How about answering his question first. Your question looks very much like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm sorry @Erbureth as you can see i'm new to the forum and still trying to get cozy with it. Im just trying to use a BIOS interrupt to print a string rather than using readymade functions or stream objects.I am just curious. I hope that clears it.

Comment: @krish: your only resort to do *what*? the interrupts you mention is the "api" to interact with DOS, it has nothing to do with standard c++. If you are asking how to do something in standard c++, then *tell us **what** you want to do*

Comment: @PlasmaHH  I would like to display a string using a softawre interrupt in c++. Now how would i cause an software interrupt using a c++ standard library function.(if any).

Comment: @krish: why does it need to be via a software interrupt? C++ doesnt have software interrupts. So you must target a specific OS that does it via some interrupt, and then you must state which one, and use tools that target it. And you should tell us why just displaying a string on standard out is not enough for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling interrupts to get a string printed worked only on `x86`-compatible CPUs working in `real mode` (which DOS ran under). Modern operating systems work in `protected mode` in which BIOS interrupts are no longer available.

Today, console output is typically represented by a `file handle` to which you send data using standard library or, if you want to do it low-level, direct kernel functions. (In POSIX system the call is  [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write))

From [Linux System Call table](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html) you can use `sys_write` available under `int 0x80` (You need to use inline assembly to fill the parameters and call the interrupt)

Comment: I wish someone had told this to me earlier.thanks mate. if i emulate a turbo c++ program in 16 bit environment(dos box) will i still be able to access the interrupt in a modern OS like win 8.

Comment: @krish: Of course! If you use DosBox, you will have most of the old'n'good BIOS and MS-DOS functions to play with. But you will have to use a MS-DOS compiler to build your program! Take a look at `DJGPP`(http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/). But my advice would be to upgrade your knowledge a bit and forget the old ways. It has been 20 years since the last MS-DOS version!!!